# Reuse result from first observable in second in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, observable

The result of the first observable (`itemsCache.GetAllKeys()`) is a list of strings. If that list contains certain string (`DOKUMENTI_KEY`), then the second observable should be called. If the first observable doesn't contain the string, then an empty list should be returned.

```
    public static IObservable<TResult> If<TSource, TResult>(
                this IObservable<TSource> source,
                Func<TSource, bool> predicate,
                Func<TSource, IObservable<TResult>> thenSource,
                Func<TSource, IObservable<TResult>> elseSource)
            {
                return source
                  .SelectMany(
                    value => predicate(value)
                      ? thenSource(value)
                      : elseSource(value));
            }

    public IObservable<List<Dokument>> GetDokumenti()
            {
                return Observable.If(
                    () => itemsCache.GetAllKeys().SelectMany(x => x).Contains(DOKUMENTI_KEY).GetAwaiter().GetResult(),
                    itemsCache.GetAllKeys().SelectMany(y => y).Where(a => a == DOKUMENTI_KEY).SelectMany(z => itemsCache.GetObject<List<Dokument>>(z)),
                    Observable.Return(new List<Dokument>())
                );

        }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"

Comment: I'm calling itemsCache.GetAllKeys() method twice instead of using result from first call. With better I mean if there is a way to somehow chain those two methods and eliminate need for If function.

Comment: Assign the result of your first `GetAllKeys` call to a variable, and use that variable for your second `SelectMany` call.